# What goes wrong when I try to create the following probability distribution on the first uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, ordinals, normal-number

This question was inspired by the well-known fact that there's no uniform probability distribution on a countably infinite set, because this would contradict $\sigma$-additivity of the probability measure.
I can't have an countably infinite number of equal positive numbers add up to $1$, and the sum of a countably infinite number of zeroes, is still zero.

But $\sigma$-additivity would be no obstacle to a probability measure on $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal, which gave points probability zero, since $\omega_1$ isn't a union of countably many points. I had naively thought, in fact, that I *could* pull back the uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$ to a continuous distribution on $ω_1$ as follows:

1. List off all the dyadic intervals in the following order: $$I_0 := [0, 1];$$ $$I_1 := [0, 0.5], I_2 := [0.5, 1];$$ $$I_3 := [0, 0.25], I_4 := [0.25, 0.5], I_5 := [0.5, 0.75], I_6 := [0.75, 1];$$
   ...etcetera, following the same pattern.
2. Define an injection of $\omega_1$ into $[0, 1]$ using the Axiom of Choice as follows. For each nonnegative integer $n$, pick an arbitrary element $x_n$ of the $n$th interval, different from any that came before.
   Then, for each ordinal of the form $ω + n$, $n \geq 0$, pick an element $x_{\omega + n}$ of the $n$th interval different than any previous choice.
   Then the same for each ordinal of the form $ω \cdot 2 + n$, $n \geq 0$.
   ...
   Then the same for each ordinal of the form $ω^2 + n = \omega \cdot \omega + n$, $n \geq 0$.
   Then the same for each ordinal of the form $ω^2 + ω + n = (ω + 1) \cdot ω + n$, $n \geq 0$.
   ...
   And so on by transfinite induction; for every non-finite countable ordinal $\alpha$ and all nonnegative integers $n$, we are choosing a new element $x_{\alpha \cdot ω + n}$ of the $n$th interval to correspond to the ordinal $\alpha \cdot ω + n$, which is always possible since all of our original intervals are uncountable.
   Eventually our construction yields an injection $$\iota: \omega_1 \to [0, 1],$$ whose image $\mathcal{S} := \iota( \omega_1 )$ is an uncountable dense set which has the property that $\mathcal{S} \cap (a, b)$ is also uncountable (*i.e. $\iota^{-1}((a, b))$ is cofinal in $\omega_1$*) for all $0 \leq a < b \leq 1$.

My intuition was that I could just define a probability distribution $\Bbb{P}: \omega_1 \to [0, 1]$ using the $\sigma$-algebra on $\omega_1$ generated by the preimages $\iota^{-1}((a, b)) \subset \omega_1$, with the obvious probability assignment $$\Bbb{P}(\iota^{-1}((a, b))) = b - a,$$ ***regardless of the particular injection I constructed, or the individual choices of $x_{\alpha \cdot \omega + n}$.***
My reasoning was, once I have an uncountable, dense subset of $[0, 1]$, any cover of that set by a countable set of open intervals (which seemingly, would combine to form $[0, 1]$ minus the countably many endpoints of those intervals, a set of full measure), would have to have Lebesgue outer measure $1$, regardless of whether $\mathcal{S}$ itself was measurable or not. (*I know this wouldn't work if $\mathcal{S}$ was countable because I could just list the points of $\mathcal{S}$ off, cover the $n$th point of $\mathcal{S}$ by an open interval of length $\epsilon \cdot 2^{-n}$, and get an outer measure of $\epsilon$.*)
However, the Strong Law of Large Numbers/Borel's normal number theorem furnishes multiple simple examples of uncountable dense sets whose intersection with any subinterval of $[0, 1]$ is also uncountable dense, yet which have Lebesgue measure $0$.
For instance, if I accidentally constructed $\mathcal{S}$ so that all $x \in \mathcal{S}$ had the digit $1$ appear twice as frequently as $0$ in their binary expansion (asymptotically speaking), then this clearly couldn't work because my "pullback" probability would have to be zero on every subset of $\omega_1$.

My question is, what am I missing? Clearly my intuition on the outer measure is leading me astray here. If someone can clarify the mistake in my thinking, I'd be much obliged.

**Edit:** To clarify, I did not expect that every subset of $\omega_1$ would have a probability/be measurable under the pullback, as explicitly stated:

> *My intuition was that I could just define a probability distribution $\Bbb{P}: \omega_1 \to [0, 1]$ **using the $\sigma$-algebra on $\omega_1$ generated by the preimages $\iota^{-1}((a, b)) \subset \omega_1$***

By referencing a particular $\sigma$-algebra I intended to clarify which subsets of $\omega_1$ would be measurable under $\Bbb{P}$. I hope that clears up any further confusion.

Comment: You write about a probability distribution $\Bbb{P}: \omega_1 \to [0, 1].$ Presumably, you want the distribution really to be defined on the powerset of $\omega_1$.

Comment: Correct, I’m being casual (perhaps overly so) with the terminology, and strictly speaking I should say it’s the elementary events that are assigned probability zero, not the outcomes per se.

Comment: Well, under the continuum hypothesis you actually get a bijection $h:\omega_1\to [0,1]$. The problem with your approach then reduces to the problem of extending Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ to the powerset.

Comment: @michael Under the continuum hypothesis I could get a bijection, but I could still get a strict injection. I could even get a map onto a Vitali set.

Comment: Yes, and? Anyways, you never show that your construction gives a measure, which is presumably where the proof would break down (there exists no such measure on $\omega_1$.)

Comment: Michael, if I understood why this construction didn’t just trivially pull back to a measure, the question would not be here for you to read right now. If you’d care to school me, that’s what the answer box down below is for.

Comment: While I can give you a proof that there is no nontrivial finite measure on the powerset of $\omega_1$ that vanishes on singletons, I can't point to problems in attempted proof steps that are not there.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Well, it's a good thing this isn't a proof verification problem, lol. I know I'm mistaken. What you just outlined would suffice.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Also, your proof assumes CH is false, correct? Since otherwise the probability measure on $[0, 1]$ itself would be a refutation. I'm not looking for a probability measure that assigns zero measure to singletons AND tags every single subset of $\omega_1$ as measurable, it's trivial that that's not possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118275/discussion-between-michael-greinecker-and-rivers-mcforge).